# Archived web content without going to the website

Tags: open-source, html-content-extraction, webarchive

I want to fetch web data without going to the actual website.

http://archive.org/web/web.php is an example which keeps the snapshots of websites. Problem with this is that data is quite old (5-6 months).

Do we have any other archive storage where recent html content can be found?

Thanks

Comment: Check out archivebox.io, it might be helpful as it creates a local, static, browsable HTML snapshot of websites you give it (it saves HTML, JS, media files, PDFs, screenshot, static assets, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to curl the website?
you can use php to cURL some web page:

 http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

or you can use command, wget or curl, in Unix:

 http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_curl.htm

Comment: many websites block after multiple 'wget'. I don't think wget will help to make extensive calls.

Comment: thanks, I think, curl can also be used in unix command line, updated. :)